# Android drawCircle compatibility problems

Tags: android, paint, ondraw

I've got custom widget - blinking circle in custom frequency. In my onDraw method i paint a circle.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
  super.onDraw(c);
  if (data[mBitIndex] == '1'){
    c.drawCircle(c.getWidth() / 2, c.getHeight() / 2, c.getWidth() / 2, mPaint);
  }
}
```

This works perfect on android 4.2.1, but if i try this on android 2.3, no circle shown. I've done some experiments to determine the problem

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
  super.onDraw(c);
  if (data[mBitIndex] == '1'){
    c.drawColor(mPaint.getColor());
  }
}
```

This works as i expected on both versions of android. But, it's a square, not circle, which i want.

How is it even possible to draw square, but not circle? I've searching on the internet, but noone has this problem before or it's only my problem. I don't get this, can anyone explain me where could be mistake?

Answer (score 0):

On Honeycomb (API 13) or earlier, the hardware acceleration is buggy and cannot draw your circle.
Disable hardware acceleration for your view:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

This worked for me.

Or set targetSDKVersion to 14 or higher (which might cause other issues).